# Apple/fastlane submit for review action failing with unclear error message about privacy text

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

I am following fastlane's default configuration conventions for a React Native project. That is to say, my project structure looks like (e.g.):

```
/ios/fastlane/metadata/en-GB
```

with the `en-GB` subdirectory containing the following files:

```
description.txt
keywords.txt
name.txt
privacy_url.txt
release_notes.txt
support_url.txt
```

Everything was working perfectly until I tried to internationalise.

Now, when fastlane's `upload_to_app_store()` (aliased with `deliver()`) runs in my CI/CD pipeline, it fails and I see the following error:

```bash
The provided entity is missing a required attribute - You must provide a value for the attribute 'privacyPolicyText' with this request - /data/attributes/privacyPolicyText
```

I already have `privacy_url.txt` in there which was previously sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that fixed it was adding a `apple_tv_privacy_policy.txt` (just containing a URL pointing to our privacy policy) file to the `en-GB` subdirectory.

Weird, given that the `Fastfile` was working completely fine before without any sort of privacy policy for TV. Very frustrating error message!